# D file I/O functions

Tags: file, io, d

I'm just learning D.  Looks like a great language, but I can't find any info about the file I/O functions.  I may be being dim (I'm good at that!), so could somebody point me in the right direction, please?
Thanks

Comment: @Kenny: "Just learning" would imply the version currently "recommended for new projects" for me, i.e., 2.

Answer (score 10):

Basically, you use [the `File` structure](http://www.digimars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_stdio.html#File) from `std.stdio`.

```
import std.stdio;

void writeTest() {
    auto f = File("1.txt", "w");        // create a file for writing,
    scope(exit) f.close();              //   and close the file when we're done.
                                        //   (optional)
    f.writeln("foo");                   // write 2 lines of text to it.
    f.writeln("bar");
}

void readTest() {
    auto f = File("1.txt");             // open file for reading,
    scope(exit) f.close();              //   and close the file when we're done.
                                        //   (optional)
    foreach (str; f.byLine)             // read every line in the file,
      writeln(":: ", str);              //   and print it out.
}

void main() {
   writeTest();
   readTest();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about the [`std.stdio`](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_stdio.html) module?

Answer (score 3):

For stuff related specifically to files (file attributes, reading/writing a file in one go), look in `std.file`.  For stuff that generalizes to standard streams (stdin, stdout, stderr) look in `std.stdio`.  You can use `std.stdio.File` for both physical disk files and standard streams.  Don't use `std.stream`, as this is scheduled for deprecation and doesn't work with ranges (D's equivalent to iterators).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find C-style file I/O favourable. I find it one of the most clear to use I/O's, especially if you work with binary files. Even in C++ I don't use streams, beside added safety it's just plain clumsy (much as I prefer printf over streams, excellent how D has a type-safe printf!).